# How can i include Proxy Server authentication in a Rest request?

Tags: c#, rest-client, proxy-server

I have a rest request as follows

```
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.GET, Resource = $"v2/userdetails" };
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserDetails>>(response.Content);
            return null;
```

It returns null, I was informed that there is a Proxy Server in the middle.

So do I need to include the proxy server settings in the request and authenticate first ?
If so how can i do  that ?

Comment: You do not. Either you have a transparent proxy, in which case you have not need to be aware of it. Or, you have an explicit proxy, in which case you need to pass the WebProxy into RestClient, at which point you can give credentials to the WebProxy object.

Comment: its an explicit proxy and im assuming if i pass the WebProxy into RestClient with credentials ,if they authenticate then the Rest  request data is returned , if not then null ?  Is there an example of this as its first time im incorporating a Proxy in my rest request ?

Comment: cant i authenticate to the proxy server and if successful then do the rest request ?

Comment: It is only `null` because your code returns null. `response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK` will fail, because you should get a Http 407  Error.